# How to map an array, create promises, and break when one resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, promise, bluebird

I've been working with the bluebird library's Promise.map function, which is returning me an Array of resolved promises, from the array it receives - as it should.

I only want to map the over the array until it reaches a first resolve, then it and exit.

What I have so far is:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

let comparer = async function (img1, imgURLarray) {

        const img = img1

        new Promise.map(imgURLarray, function (imgurl) {

            let img2 = new Promise(x => x(Jimp.read('https:' + imgurl)))

            let diff = Jimp.diff(await img, await img2);

            return diff.percent


        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }); 

comparer(img1, imgURLarray)
```

The param img1 is an `Object` constant, while imgURLarray is contains over 200 `Strings` which are compared 1:1 - Through the library Jimp.

Instead of returning an entire array of 200+ Jimp.diff objects. I want to return only the first which satisfies this condition:

```
(diff.percent < 0.01 ? return imgurl : --END MAP FUNCTION-- )
```

I looked into Promise.some(), but since I'm not starting with an array of promises I don't think that would work. Anyone know how it could be done? Would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to start all 200 diffs at once, or try one after the other until you find one that satisfies your condition?

Comment: What exactly does `Jimp.read` return? Can you link its docs? Wrapping it in an (other?) promise seems quite useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably much simpler than you expected:

```
async function comparer(img, imgURLarray) {
    for (const imgurl of imgURLarray);
        const otherimg = await Jimp.read('https:' + imgurl);
        const diff = Jimp.diff(img, otherimg);
        if (diff.percent < 0.01)
            return imgurl;
    }
    throw new Error("no imgurl with diff.percent < 0.01 found"); // or whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Spot on with the answer! thank you so much it's scary how much fast this is!!! I was definitely over complicating it